# Vimeo API: get mp4 links of own videos over php api

Tags: php, vimeo-api

I would like to get the mp4 links of my own videos for my own website. So I've created a vimeo app and generated a personal access token with following scopes: private, public.

Now I tried to call the data of a video and this is the response: "invalid siganture". I dont't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
    if ( ! defined( 'OPCT_VIMEO_CLIENT_ID' ) ) {
        define( 'OPCT_VIMEO_CLIENT_ID', '1234' );
    }

    if ( ! defined( 'OPCT_VIMEO_CLIENT_SECRET' ) ) {
        define( 'OPCT_VIMEO_CLIENT_SECRET', 'dfgdfgdfgE44rrfd/xsdfsdfsdGDFDFGdfgdfg/dfgdfgdfgdfgdf/' );
    }

    if ( ! defined( 'OPCT_VIMEO_ACCESS_TOKEN' ) ) {
        define( 'OPCT_VIMEO_ACCESS_TOKEN', '1234' );
    }

    if ( ! class_exists( 'phpVimeo' ) ) {
        include_once 'lib/vimeo.php';
    }

    try {
        $vimeo    = new phpVimeo( OPCT_VIMEO_CLIENT_ID, OPCT_VIMEO_CLIENT_SECRET );
        $response = $vimeo->call( 'videos', array( 'video_id', '1234567890' ) );
        $this->log( $response );
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        $this->log( 'Vimeo Error API Call: ' . $e->getMessage() );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you include is part of the old Vimeo library, which uses the old Vimeo API.

The old Vimeo API does not expose source files, so you will need to use the new library as found here: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

The code will look similar to the following in the new library (Note I have not tested this)

```
if ( ! defined( 'OPCT_VIMEO_CLIENT_ID' ) ) {
    define( 'OPCT_VIMEO_CLIENT_ID', '1234' );
}

if ( ! defined( 'OPCT_VIMEO_CLIENT_SECRET' ) ) {
    define( 'OPCT_VIMEO_CLIENT_SECRET', 'dfgdfgdfgE44rrfd/xsdfsdfsdGDFDFGdfgdfg/dfgdfgdfgdfgdf/' );
}

if ( ! defined( 'OPCT_VIMEO_ACCESS_TOKEN' ) ) {
    define( 'OPCT_VIMEO_ACCESS_TOKEN', '1234' );
}

if ( ! class_exists( 'phpVimeo' ) ) {
    include_once 'lib/vimeo.php';
}

try {
    $vimeo    = new Vimeo\Vimeo( OPCT_VIMEO_CLIENT_ID, OPCT_VIMEO_CLIENT_SECRET );
    $response = $vimeo->request( '/videos/' . $video_id);
    $this->log( $response );
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    $this->log( 'Vimeo Error API Call: ' . $e->getMessage() );
}
```

You will then find the video files in the `$response` variable.